# How to access a file in SSRS report?

Tags: c#, vb.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to get information from a file to a field in `.rdl` report. I am opening the report in *Report Builder 3.0 2014* (with intention to use it in the *Report Viewer*).

First I have created a function in the report (report properties/code) containing

```
Using sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName))
'...
End Using
```

The result was `#Error` in the target field.

So I have created a strongly named DLL with `[Assembly: SecurityRules(Security.SecurityRuleSet.Level2)]` (or `Level1`) and `[Assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]`, installed it to GAC and  added a DLL reference in the *report properties/references*.

The library contains the function

```
public string test(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName)))
        {
           return "OK"
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

which resulted in

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)

Running the `Report Builder` as Admin (obviously?) did not help.

**Is there another way of reading a file? Have I omitted any OS or Report Builder option?**

Comment: Did you add an assembly reference in the report (report properties -> assemblies)?

Comment: @AlanSchofield: I forgot to mention. The assembly reference is added to report properties -> References.